# Simple JS question about variables || Variables

Tags: javascript

I have below code:

```
 <script>
            var a2 = false;
            if (document.dir == "rtl"){
                alert("rtl exist");
                a2 = true;
        }else{
                alert("rtl doesnt exist");
                a2 = false;
        }
        </script>
```

This code works.Also I have below code:

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.vertical-center-4').slick({
                    centerMode: false,
                    slidesToShow: 2,
                    infinite: true,
                    rtl: true,
                    slidesToScroll: 2,
                    //speed: 300, bla bla...  this code continues like this
```

There is a phare above code like this :    `rtl: true,`

I want to turn it true if rtl exist, if does not exist, I want to turn it to false.

How can I change the "true" phare to a variable? I searched it bit but I couldnt find good resource about JS variables.

**Edit:**

May you confuse because you dont have all code and in everything there are some code about "rtl".As a simple, I want to change "true" word which part of this line :    rtl: true, to a variable.So, I want to write a2 instead of that word.

Comment: `Boolean(rtl)` will return true if it's not `null` or `undefined` or `false` or..., and false otherwise, or you can use **ternary operators**

Comment: @SaymoinSam I am new at Js, my question is so simple.Also I editted the question just now.I want to change the "true" word to a variable, for example to "a2".

Comment: Just use the `a2` variable in place of where you would put your boolean value, ie `rtl: a2` instead of `rtl: true`. You can even streamline it like `rtl: (document.dir === 'rtl'),` that way you wont need the variable at all, unless needed for other parts in your code

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks, your code works.